# Can't clear cache Symfony in production

Tags: caching, doctrine, symfony-2.7, http-status-code-500

Despite of all my attempts to understand the problem, I still can't figure out what is happening. 
I developped a website with Symfony 2.7 which perfectly works in dev mode. When I tested it in production mode, an error 500 is returned.

The exception is :

```
 Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: 
 "Error: Call to a member function getCacheFactory() on a non-object" at
  /home/admdev-php/public_html/sfSUAPS/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 3039 
 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): 
 Error: Call to a member function getCacheFactory() on a non-object at
  /home/admdev-php/public_html/sfSUAPS/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:3039)"} []
```

So I've tried to clear the cache and I had the same message :

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                                                  
   Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required 
 '/home/stagiaire/workspace/suaps/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppBundleEntityPlace.php' 
 (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')`
```

I've tried to clear doctrine's cache but this doesn't solve the problem.

There are severals roles : One for students, one for teachers and one for admins. I only get this error when my role is student. So I looked closer to methods which are concerned and I commented everything related to studies and it worked. So I think the error is linked with my Entity Repository since "findBy" and "findAll" are failing.

I've took a look into Symfony's code but the error seems to be on my side. I really don't know what is going on, thank you if you can help me.

**Problem solved**

Turns out someone used an entity directly from cache...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out someone used an entity directly from cache...

```
use Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Place;
```